# Size and position of the text filed of the uisearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can I control the size and position of the text filed of the uisearchbar?and how?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has the answer you're looking for,
 [Change the font size of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697689/changing-font-size-of-uisearchbar),

```
for(int i =0; i<[searchbar.subviews count]; i++) {
    if([[searchbar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        [(UITextField*)[searchbar.subviews objectAtIndex:i]setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]];
}
```

As you can see, just use `setFrame` instead `setFont`.

I guess it should work !

Good Luck !