# Change font for a programmatically created UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have found that the code in my `AppDelegate`:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
```

works to change the font of a `UISearchBar` created from IB.  No problems there.

However, if I create the `UISearchBar` in code as such:

```
UISearchBar *bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
bar.placeholder = @"test";
[self.view addSubview:bar];
```

Then the above `UITextField` appearance code has no effect.  Is there a way to change the font of a programmatically created `UISearchBar`?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess this answer will work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697689/change-the-font-size-of-uisearchbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
UITextField *textField = [[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
[textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:25]];
```

for more reference check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697689/change-the-font-size-of-uisearchbar)

Comment: Thank you, this worked, although I used a for() loop to check the class just in case.

Comment: crashes in `iOS7`. What about that?

Comment: This is not recommended way... instead follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697689/change-the-font-size-of-uisearchbar/46664960#46664960

Answer (score 4):

Try this,It's Working Fine for iOS 5.0 and up: (iOS 7 also)

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"League Gothic" size:20]];
```

Comment: In iOS 7 this works for me only if I call it after the UISearchBar is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
UITextField *textField = [self.searchBar valueForKey: @"_searchField"];
[textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.0]];
```

Hope this will help.