# How can I programmatically change UIFont of UISearchBar or UITableViewHeader?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` to which I add programmatically a `UISearchController` as a header. Since I'm adding it programmatically, I can't change the font from the storyboard. I need to change the `UISearchBar` font to match the font of the rest of the app.  I would need to either change the font of a `UISearchBar` or of the whole `tableViewHeader`

I saw that there's a similar question with an answer in objective-c, however I'm developing my app in **Swift** and I tried to convert the answer on the other question to the following code but it still won't work :

```
let lightFont = UIFont(name: "GothamRounded-Light", size: 15)

        for subview in searchController.searchBar.subviews {
            if subview is UITextField{

                (subview as! UITextField).font = lightFont

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697689/change-the-font-size-of-uisearchbar)

You'll need to loop through it's subviews to find the UITextField (not accessible by property)

```
for subview in search.subviews {
   if subview is UITextField {
       (subview as! UITextField).font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24.0)
   }
}
```

Then you can set it's font.

Comment: Thanks, that looks right to be but when I run it, the font it's not changing. I updated my question with the code I'm using!

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not finding the subviews that are UITextField. Do you have any idea why could that be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let textFieldInSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
textFieldInSearchBar?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in **viewDidLoad()**

```
let textFieldInsideUISearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField

let placeholderLabel = textFieldInsideUISearchBar?.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel

placeholderLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 13.0) //this will set custom font to placeholder font

textFieldInsideUISearchBar?.font = placeholderLabel?.font //this will set custom font to text font
```

This will set a custom font to both the placeholder and text in the `UISearchBar`.

Answer (score -1):

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here,  and address why you feel this is a good answer?