# How to customize search bar iOS

Tags: swift, user-interface, uisearchbar, xcode-storyboard

I am using storyboards to make a search bar using UISearchBar. I am trying to make it look like this:
[image: sketch design]

However this is what I end up getting:
[image: actual app]

I've added code to change the bar's dimensions and set a minimum font size for the text (for auto layout) and add corner radius. The only code that works is the corner radius unfortunately.

`searchBarOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 10
searchBarOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 304
searchBarOutlet.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Show your relevant code, as text, in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy I've added the code

Comment: 1. That code is far from enough. Show how you create and size the search bar. 2. Why would you set the `borderWidth` to 304? That's normally only 1 or 2.

Comment: @rmaddy I created the search bar via storyboard not via code

Answer (score 0):

You can set the search bar style to "Minimal" in the properties inspector, I think that's more close to what are you looking for, regarding the the font size and autolayout issues I think there is no way to access those properties in the UISearchBar, but there are workarounds like the one specified here [Change the font size of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697689/change-the-font-size-of-uisearchbar)

The other workaround you can try it's making your own "loook a like" search bar, which shouldn't be that hard, maybe the hardest part will be to add small icon to the left of the placeholder

Comment: Thank you. However, when I set to minimal it's transparent, I need it to be white.